# Running Arima in python after using ADFfuller giving me error

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a dataset like below,

```
yearmonth   Count
1/1/2014    104
2/1/2014    47
3/1/2014    83
4/1/2014    72
5/1/2014    101
6/1/2014    135
7/1/2014    75
8/1/2014    83
9/1/2014    86
10/1/2014   78
11/1/2014   24
12/1/2014   24
1/1/2015    87
2/1/2015    33
3/1/2015    49
4/1/2015    79
5/1/2015    110
6/1/2015    104
7/1/2015    105
8/1/2015    100
9/1/2015    79
10/1/2015   72
11/1/2015   104
12/1/2015   26
1/1/2016    127
2/1/2016    50
3/1/2016    96
4/1/2016    87
5/1/2016    127
6/1/2016    102
7/1/2016    78
8/1/2016    99
9/1/2016    52
10/1/2016   103
11/1/2016   53
12/1/2016   30
1/1/2017    150
2/1/2017    57
3/1/2017    81
4/1/2017    61
5/1/2017    85
6/1/2017    103
7/1/2017    77
8/1/2017    45
9/1/2017    47
```

on which i want to fit a time series model. SO I checked stationarity with all 4 options of adf test, as mentioned below

```
adfuller(var, maxlag=None, regression='c', autolag='AIC', store=False, regresults=False)
adfuller(var, maxlag=None, regression='ct', autolag='AIC', store=False, regresults=False)
adfuller(var, maxlag=None, regression='ctt', autolag='AIC', store=False, regresults=False)
adfuller(var, maxlag=None, regression='nc', autolag='AIC', store=False, regresults=True)
```

In all the four cased the null hypothesis (the data is non-stationary) is rejected with very small p value. That means we can run an arima model with d=0. I also checked Ljung Box Statitics with the same conclusion.
Now I tried to run

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(var, order=(1,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
```

It is giving me the following error. I'm not sure, why?

> raise ValueError("The computed initial AR coefficients are not "
>
> ValueError: The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary
> You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order, or you
> can pass your own start_params.
> Can somebody please tell me what is happening here?